# Мультиязычность на PHP

Tags: php

Скажите, как ЛУЧШЕ, каким способом реализовать мультиязычный сайт на PHP?

Полазив по просторам интернета я могу подчеркнуть 3 способа:

1. Использование БД MYSQL.
2. Использовать JSON файлы.
3. Утилита `gettext`.

В моем проекте Сайт-визитка я думаю лучше использовать комбинированный подход, используя БД и JSON, потому что если добавлять новую информацию(например через админ панель), то можно без особых трудов обновить информацию, как в БД так и в JSON. Однако я считаю, что данный подход не совсем корректный.

Если посмотреть в сторону утилиты `gettext`, то можно сказать, что это идеальный подход для реализации мультиязычности. Все красиво и понятно разбито на папки с определенным языком, в каждой этой папке есть .po и .mo файлы в которых есть `msgid` и `msgstr`, однако есть проблемы с освоением этой технологии. На сегодняшний(на 3 день изучения gettext) у меня наконец то удалось создать успешно тестовый проект с Хелло Ворлд и то он работает в корне не так как пишется в блогах, инструкциях и т.д. Плюс я понятия не имею как можно с админ панели обновлять файлы .po и .mo, поскольку для создания .mo файла нужно откомпилировать .po файл....

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/i18n.html

Answer (score 1):

Файлы `.po` и `.mo` используются, например, в вордпрессе по факту, то есть перевод темы, по сути. И да, для создания `.mo` используются специальные утилиты, а также библиотеки для языков. Например, если погуглить, то можно найти нечто подобное - https://github.com/bigwhoop/potomoco (не юзал, не знаю).

Однако учтите, что конвертировать каждый чих пользователя может обойтись вам дорого. В Yii, например, раньше использовали перевод на файлах текстовых (сейчас не знаю), но опять таки, только той инфы, которая **не меняется ДИНАМИЧЕСКИ**, через админку.

Итог: Используйте БД, gettext создавался для перевода **программ**, где всего-то нужно перевести пару строк текста, а не целые тома "Войны и Мира".